# Release Mode Cannot connect to Database Whereas Debug Mode connect to in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I created n-tier architure project in .Net Core 3.0 and I used SQL Server 2017.

In debug mode it works well but after I publish it and transferred to server it doesn't work*.

I installed VS2019 in server too to find the problem but I couldn't get anything. Still it works in debug mode and doesn't work after publish...

*I add some html data and some remote (database) data. Browser shows only html data... I cannot login too. How can I find the problem?

Comment: How did you publish it and transferred to server?Where did you host your project?

Comment: I publish to a folder then copy from my pc to server through remote connection. I host my project in a MS Server 2019 machine.

Comment: I change my database to PostgreSQL, it works.... It's veri interesting...